# Question on The multiplicative magic square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, magic-square

Consider this magic square:

> $$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline a & b & c \\ \hline d & e & f \\ \hline j & h & i \\ \hline  \end{array} $$
> Where $a,b,c,d,e,f,j,h,i\in \mathbb N^*$ and the $\gcd$ of all nine elements is $1$.
> This magic square is A multiplicative one such that the product in each row, column and diagonal is equal to $P$

**The first question:** Prove that $e^3=P$

**The second question:** construct a multiplicative magic square with the divisors of $100$

**My attempt:**

It’s not actually an attempt, it is just an observation, since the $\gcd(a,b,c,d,e,f,j,h,i)=1$ And $$aei=cej=beh=def=P$$
$e\in\mathbb N^* \implies e\geq1$, so we can divde by it:
$$ai=cj=bh=df$$
Wich mean that $a\mid cj,bh,df$ And $i\mid cj,bh,df$ and so on..., but what’s next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^3=\frac{aei\cdot beh\cdot ceg}{abc\cdot ghi}=\frac{P^3}{P^2}=P$$

---

The knight move strategy seems to work just as in the additive case:

$$\begin{matrix}50 &1&20\\4&10& 25\\5&100 &2\end{matrix}$$

Comment: How could an idea like this come to me? It seems tricky

Comment: @Yassir In additive magic table, central number is arithmetic mean. For same reason here, the central number is geometric mean. Rest of the numbers are filled in similar manner.

Comment: In fact, taking logarithm on the geometric square, these results are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with any additive magic square. The following are the simplest

\begin{array}{c}
   \begin{pmatrix}
       0 & 2 & 1 \\
       2 & 1 & 0 \\
       1 & 0 & 2 \\
   \end{pmatrix} &
   \begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 0 & 2 \\
       2 & 1 & 0 \\
       0 & 2 & 1 \\
   \end{pmatrix} &
   \begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 2 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 & 2 \\
       2 & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{pmatrix} &
   \begin{pmatrix}
       2 & 0 & 1 \\
       0 & 1 & 2 \\
       1 & 2 & 0 \\
   \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{array}

Pick one or more and associate each to an array of some chosen base raised to those powers.
For example.

\begin{array}{c}
   \begin{pmatrix}
       2^0 & 2^2 & 2^1 \\
       2^2 & 2^1 & 2^0 \\
       2^1 & 2^0 & 2^2 \\
   \end{pmatrix} &
   \begin{pmatrix}
       3^1 & 3^0 & 3^2 \\
       3^2 & 3^1 & 3^0 \\
       3^0 & 3^2 & 3^1 \\
   \end{pmatrix} &
   \begin{pmatrix}
       5^1 & 5^2 & 5^0 \\
       5^0 & 5^1 & 5^2 \\
       5^2 & 5^0 & 5^1 \\
   \end{pmatrix}
\end{array}

Simplify.
\begin{array}{c}
   \begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 4 & 2 \\
       4 & 2 & 1 \\
       2 & 1 & 4 \\
   \end{pmatrix} &
   \begin{pmatrix}
       3 & 1 & 9 \\
       9 & 3 & 1 \\
       1 & 9 & 3 \\
   \end{pmatrix} &
   \begin{pmatrix}
       5 & 25 & 1 \\
       1 & 5 & 25 \\
       25 & 1 & 5 \\
   \end{pmatrix}
\end{array}

Create one array by multiplying pointwise.

\begin{pmatrix}
       15 & 100 & 18 \\
       36 & 30 & 25 \\
       50 & 9 & 60 \\
   \end{pmatrix}